# Python shell command to clear

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6. How do I clear the python shell, something equivalent to Cls command in DOS? I read on some sites that ctrl + L should do the job, but, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the REPL environment from the command-line (e.g. running python on a dos command-line or within a posix terminal/tty), there's no mechanism that the REPL provides to clear the screen.

So for example, you may run:

```
c:\> python
>>>
```

The above has no way to clear the command-line.

But may I suggest [ipython](https://ipython.org/)?

It's a better, more full-featured python REPL interface for command-line execution and also includes a way to clear the screen.